# Runtime error Arithmetic Exception divide by zero

Tags: java, divide-by-zero

This is getting Runtime Error

```
Exception Name: java.lang.ArithmeticException
Exception Message: / by zero
```

How I can avoid that?

```
 else if(((arr1[3]-arr1[1])/(arr1[2]-arr1[0]))==-1/((arr2[3]-arr2[1])/(arr2[2]-arr2[0]))){
            System.out.println("YES");
```

Comment: Use a try catch block.
catch ArithematicException in the first catch block and then catch Exception in following catch block after it.

Comment: I have done this , still not passing showing runtime error        
            try{
                if((arr1[3] == arr1[1] && arr1[2]== arr1[0]) || (arr2[3] == arr2[1] && arr2[2]== arr2[0])){
                    System.out.println("INVALID"); else if(((arr1[3]-arr1[1])/(arr1[2]-arr1[0]))==-1/((arr2[3]-arr2[1])/(arr2[2]-arr2[0]))){
                    System.out.println("YES");
                    
                }else{
                    System.out.println("NO");
                }
}
           catch(ArithmeticException e){
                System.out.println("NO");
              }

Comment: *"How I can avoid that?"* Don't try to divide by zero, i.e. when `arr1[2] == arr1[0]` *or* `arr2[3] == arr2[1]` *or* `arr2[2] == arr2[0]`.

Comment: @rishabh_95 Don't post code in a comment. **Edit** the question and post the code there to *clarify* the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your denominator is resulting to zero. Handle this situation on how you want to proceed if denominator of your division results in a zero value.

Comment: I have handled this, still showing error
            try{
                if((arr1[3] == arr1[1] && arr1[2]== arr1[0]) || (arr2[3] == arr2[1] && arr2[2]== arr2[0])){
                    System.out.println("INVALID"); }
                
   else if(((arr1[3]-arr1[1])/(arr1[2]-arr1[0]))==-1/((arr2[3]-arr2[1])/(arr2[2]-arr2[0]))){
                    System.out.println("YES");
                    
                }else{
                    System.out.println("NO");
                }
            }
            catch(ArithmeticException e){
                System.out.println("NO");}